# Serving an HTML Page from Azure PowerShell Function

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions, serverless, faas

I try to serve a HTML Page from an Azure **PowerShell** Function. I am able to return the HTML but I have clue where I can set the **content type to text/htm**l in order that the Browser interprets the HTML.

Here is an [example from Anythony Chu](https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-serve-html/) how you can do it in C#:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream(@"d:\home\site\wwwroot\ShoppingList\index.html", FileMode.Open);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return response;
}
```

But in a PowerShell function I just return the file using the `Out-File` cmdlet and don't have the option to set the content type. Here a hello world example:

```
# POST method: $req
$requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$name = $requestBody.name

# GET method: each querystring parameter is its own variable
if ($req_query_name) 
{
    $name = $req_query_name 
}

$html = @'
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
'@

Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject $html
```

Here is how the response looks like in the Browser:

[image]

Any idea how I can set the content type so that the Browser *interprets*  the HTML?

Comment: well, you could just use c# to set content type?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I don't understand your question. I want to set the content type in a Azure PowerShell function, not C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may return a Response object with properties `body`, `headers`, `status` and `isRaw` (optional):

```
$result = [string]::Format('{{ "status": 200, "body": "{0}", "headers": {{ 
"content-type": "text/html" }} }}', $html)
Out-File -Encoding Ascii $res -inputObject $result;
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy :D. Thank you very much! How did you know that?

Comment: @mikhail care to share the source?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I only have [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#response-object) for javascript